# Ubuntu uses more virtual memory than the physical memory

Tags: 11.10, memory

Ubuntu uses only 9.7% of the physical memory and 66% of the virtual memory (swap).

How can I tell the system to take advantage of the physical memory so it would run normally?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of `top`?

Comment: What is your swappiness? ( $ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness )

Comment: How much physical memory (RAM) do you have. That is important information to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to tell the system not to use `swap` is to simply turn it off:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

This way the OS will have to choice.  But if you have 66% of swap in use and only 10% of physical memory there is something very wrong.

Comment: Thanks You i'll try it                                                                            .                                                                      Any more seggestion?